# How to connect to memcached from another machine

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to use memcached from a different machine (which has access to my server), but I can't figure out how.

on the memcached machine I can test the connection by running

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 port
```

And it works, but on the other machine it just keeps trying to connect

```
telnet machine_address port
Trying machine_address...
```

I'm not sure if I should set up something else to get it working. I know the port is working and accessible because if I try to run other services on it, they works.

Os is ubuntu

Comment: I am having this same problem with my virtual machines, telnet returns "connection refused". Local telnet in the memcache machine does work. Added an explicit rule to the iptables to allow the 11211 port, no dice, added a rule in the router to allow the port, no dice...

Answer (score 27):

In /etc/memcached.conf:

```
# Specify which IP address to listen on. The default is to listen on all IP addresses
# This parameter is one of the only security measures that memcached has, so make sure
# it's listening on a firewalled interface.
-l 127.0.0.1
```

Change that to

```
-l 0.0.0.0
```

and restart memcached.

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Check the output of `netstat -ln4t` then to see if it's listening on 127.0.0.1:11211 or 0.0.0.0:11211.

Comment: the output is 0.0.0.0:*

Comment: Its embarrassing how long it took me to figure this out. Thanks @Majenko

Comment: @Majenko You are talking about `Local Address`?

Comment: You can also comment that line. Because, as the comment said, if this value is missing (`-l 127.0.0.1` by default) then memcached listens on all the IP address. I think it is better comment the line so we can always return to the default value to future references.

Answer (score 3):

Edit the `-l` line in `/etc/memcached.conf`. This is where your startup options are stored.

The following line will allow memcached to listen on all interfaces:

```
sudo sed 's/-l/#-l/' /etc/memcached.conf && sudo service memcached restart
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic possibilities:

- You've set your memcached instance to listen only on local loopback interface -- you can check this in `netstat -l` output.
- You've got your `iptables` firewall set to reject all incoming connections, except those that are explicitly allowed.

Comment: I see the port allowed on both nestat and iptables. In ip tables it reads tcp dpt:11211